# How to fix that LocationManager and GpsStatus returning no satellites

Tags: java, android, android-gps

I'm trying to set up an activity that when accessed will tell the user how many GPS satellites there are available and how strong the signal is, but since i can't even get the satellite number i'm kinda stuck.

And now that i have tried over a month to get it to work, by making the code to do it in the activity itself or up to several classes that extends and or implements the GpsStatus, GpsStatus.Listener or the LocationManager, i'm at a loss anyone got any ideas?

All of this code is in the activity itself.
I have cut out all uses of classes and code i've tried but couldn't get to work, this is the closest i have gotten and none of the counting variables returns anything but zero.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void countSatellites(){

    int satellites = 0;
    int satellitesInFix = 0;

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    GpsStatus status = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null);

    Iterable sats = status.getSatellites();
    Iterator satI = sats.iterator();
    int count = 0;

    while(satI.hasNext()){

        GpsSatellite gpssatellite = (GpsSatellite) satI.next();

        if (gpssatellite.usedInFix()){

            count++;

        }

    }


    int timetofix = locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getTimeToFirstFix();


    for (GpsSatellite sat : locationManager.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites()) {

        if (sat.usedInFix()) {

            satellitesInFix++;

        }

        satellites++;

    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {

        case 1: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (checkLocationPermission()) {

                    countSatellites();

                }

            } else {


            }

            return;

        }


    }

}


public boolean checkLocationPermission() {

    String permission = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION";

    int res = this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);

    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connections);

    LocationUpdateService locationService = new LocationUpdateService();

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


}
```

In a another file

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements GpsStatus.Listener{

    public void onCreate(){

        Log.i("on create", "success");

        super.onCreate();
        registerGpsStatusListener();

    }

    private void registerGpsStatusListener() {

        Log.i("gps listener", "success");

        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {

        Log.i("gps change", "success");

        switch (event) {

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:

                Log.e("gps started", "onGpsStatusChanged started");
                break;

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:

                Log.e("gps stopped", "onGpsStatusChanged stopped");
                break;

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:

                Log.e("gps first", "onGpsStatusChanged first fix");
                break;

            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:

                Log.e("gps status", "onGpsStatusChanged status");
                break;

        }

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("on bind", "success");
        return null;
    }


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.i("location change", "success");

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing indoors? Did you ever receive any event from `GpsStatus.Listener`? Did you ever receive a GPS location update?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Sorry for the very slow response, yes i'm testing inside right next to a window, and regarding both your other questions the answer is no i never managed to get anything from them, which is why i consider this the best i have as i'm getting something.
Should probably also say that i'm testing with a an android that runs version 4.4.2 in case that changes anything.

Comment: You could just try outdoors. If you don't even get GPS locations then probably there's nothing to report about the satellites as they simply are not found. "Assisted-GPS" will also help with the initial fix. Basically that means having a SIM card in the device, so that it can first determine the rough cell tower based location.

Comment: Okay i'll try looking into that, thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay now i have tried to use this class `public class LocationUpdateService extends Service implements GpsStatus.Listener` and i can't get anything out of it, so i'm totally lost. I'll leave the whole class up in the question.